# Adding words to a trie

Tags: c++, trie

I am creating a trie and am having trouble at the time of compiling.

The warningI get is: 
"Reading invalid data from 'currNode->dict': the readable size is '104' bytes, but '388' bytes may be read."

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 26;

struct Node {
bool isWord;
Node* dict[SIZE];
};

class Dictionary
{
public:
Dictionary();
Dictionary(string file);
void addWord(string word);

private:
Node *root;
int numWords;
};

Dictionary::Dictionary()
{
numWords = 0;
root = new Node;

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    root->dict[i] = nullptr;
}

Dictionary::Dictionary(string file)
{
numWords = 0;
root = new Node;

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    root->dict[i] = nullptr;

ifstream inFile;
string word;

inFile.open(file);

while (inFile >> word) {
    addWord(word);
    numWords++;
}
}

void Dictionary::addWord(string word)
{
int len = word.length(); // size of word
char letter;
int pos;

Node *currNode = root;

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    letter = word[i]; // takes character at position i
    pos = letter - 'a'; // finds the position of the character in the array (0 through 25)
                        // with 'a' being 0 and 'z' being 25

    if (!currNode->dict[pos]) {
        currNode->dict[pos] = new Node;

        currNode->isWord = false;
    }
    currNode = currNode->dict[pos];
}
currNode->isWord = true;
}
```

What could be causing this? I'm pretty sure that I'm not trying to access invalid memory. Perhaps it's the way I setup my node and class?

Comment: *I'm pretty sure that I'm not trying to access invalid memory* -- Please post a [mcve].  We have no idea where, when, or how any of this code comes into play.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/c6385?view=vs-2019
Is it this error/warning? Also can you specify at what lin you get this?

Comment: `pos = letter - 'a';` -- What if `pos` turns out to be negative?  Or in general, what if `pos` is not valid when you do this: `currNode->dict[pos]`?

Comment: For this assignment, I'm adding only words that are lowercase. According to ASCII, all letters after 'a' are of a higher integer, so I believe you can't get a negative.

Comment: @ThrmsNPrfs -- *I'm adding only words that are lowercase* -- That doesn't mean you just assume the character is valid.  What if it isn't?  I see no `main` program that has all lower case data.  The lesson is never write a program that is so wide-open for bugs to occur.

Answer (score 0):

One mistake is that you fail to initialize `Node` to default values.  In your `Dictionary` default constructor, you have code that really should be part of what `Node` should be doing:

```
root = new Node ;
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    root->dict[i] = nullptr;
```

This should be `Node`'s job, not the job of `Dictionary`.

Instead, you have this:

```
struct Node {
    bool isWord;
    Node* dict[SIZE];
};
```

So every time you do this:

```
if (!currNode->dict[pos]) {
    currNode->dict[pos] = new Node;
```

You are creating an uninitialized `Node` object.  That entire `Node::dict` array contains uninitialized pointers, which you later try to access.

The easiest solution is to zero-initialize the `Node` object.

```
if (!currNode->dict[pos]) {
    currNode->dict[pos] = new Node(); // <-- Note the parentheses
```

This will automatically set the `dict` pointers to `nullptr`.

---

The other method is to make sure `Node` objects are created with default values:

```
   #include <algorithm>

   struct Node {
        bool isWord;
        Node* dict[SIZE];
        Node() : isWord(false) { std::fill_n(dict, SIZE, nullptr); }
    };
```

With this, even `new Node;` will create nodes that are initialized.